# Facing GridDB Error Code (TXN_STATEMENT_TYPE_NOT_EXECUTABLE) - Unable to Execute Client Request

Tags: java, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I'm working with GridDB, and I'm facing an issue with the following details:

- Error Code: 10012
- Error Message: TXN_STATEMENT_TYPE_NOT_EXECUTABLE
- Description: Execution of client request failed.

The error seems to be occurring during the execution of a client request in my GridDB setup. The error message suggests that the problem might be related to the row lock setting, indicating that it may be incorrect.

I'm using a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

I've attempted to check whether a row lock has been specified in an operation where a row lock cannot be requested.

However, despite my efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Could someone please provide guidance on how to correctly set the row lock or offer any other suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this GridDB error?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: In the error details presented, I see nothing suggest a locking problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.